# Do not count but get the number of row

Tags: mysql

I've some problem to get the number of orders returned.

I'm trying to count the number of orders for a specific customer and with a specific status :

```
SELECT orderID FROM orders_detail WHERE userID = 1 AND statusorderID = 2
```

The query return 7 rows which is correct :

```
orderID
1
1
2
2
2
165
165
```

If I use count into my query then I get "7" returned which is correct too.

But my problem is that I would need the query returning me "3", because 1 is an order (with 2 products), 2 is an order (with 3 products) and 165 is an order too (with 2 products).

Any clue how I could get this ?

Thanks for tips, cheers, Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using `distinct orderID`

```
SELECT distinct orderID FROM orders_detail WHERE userID = 1 AND statusorderID = 2
```

OR if you want to count it you can use

```
SELECT count(distinct orderID) FROM orders_detail WHERE userID = 1 AND statusorderID = 2
```